# how to show next & prev data from database in UItextfield on click next & prev button in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

Hello i am newbie for iPhone app development. I have just created one page that contains some `UITextField` and `UILabel`. In `UITextField` i fill the text from database i call it as answers field and same as well `UILabel` is also fill from database as i call it questions.

Answer field mean `UITextField` is editable by user and rest `UILabel` is not editable it shows questions.

so it shows like wise :

1.Quesition:**text label**

answer:[**text field**]

So as show in bold text that are bind from database that shows one persons's record so i use two **button** for **next** and **previous** record.

So my question is how to move **next** and  to the **previous**  record and load in to this `UITextField` and `UILabel` on button click?

So in simple how to move & (load&)show next or previous data?

I use some PHP to load data from data base.

Please Help me to find out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While showing data in TextField from database first you have stored it anywhere may in Array.

Now while clicking on next-previous you need to simply change the index value (Increment-decrement) & display the new index value into the TextField.